# Detecting the difference between a deep sleep wake signal and a manual wake button press

Tags: esp8266

When my ESP8266 wakes itself from sleep (i.e. D0 sends wake signal), I want it to do something different to when I manually wake the device with the reset button.

I have the RST and D0 pins connected, so that the device can wake itself from sleep. I also have a button connected to RST which pulls to ground when pressed, so that I can wake the device manually on demand.

How do I differentiate between the device being awoken by itself, or manually by the button press?

I tried using `system_get_rst_info`/`getResetInfoPtr` to determine what action has awoken the device, but it seems that if I reset manually after the device went to sleep, the `REASON_DEEP_SLEEP_AWAKE` reason is returned since that value is based on how the device went to sleep/reset rather than how it woke up.

Disclaimer: I already found a solution (answer below), but it's more complex than I wanted, so I am posting this question to see if anyone else can think of a simpler solution.

Comment: if you use ntp, you could cache the expected wakeup time in rtc ram or even spiffs and compare the stored value with the established time upon reboot. If you happen to manually reset right on schedule it would mis-report, but that should be rare and you have a work-around if such precision is needed.

Comment: Oh that's a good idea!

Comment: was thinking; if you subtract millis() from the net time upon reboot, you can get a really good idea of the utc time of reset by eliminating the wifi connection time. With logging you might also realize it takes say 10ms to reset, and add that into your formula to get it even more accurate/precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with two solutions (3 if you count the combo), both involve connecting the manual reset button to another pin on the MCU (so I can check if it's still pressed when starting).

**Solution 1: Generate a reset pulse**

The problem with the manual reset button is that it's only on release that it resets, since while the RST pin is held low, the MCU won't start.

To solve this, I used a positive edge monostable circuit to pulse the RST pin when the manual reset button is pressed down.

That way, I can hold the button down and the device starts. In the `setup()` function, I can check if the button is still pressed.

**Solution 2: Use an RC delay circuit**

I also considered that I could simply wake the device on button release, and use a debounce cap (very slow discharge) to see if the button was pressed in the last second (by checking the pin on the MCU to which the charged cap is connected).

**Solution 3: A combination of 1 & 2**

Combining 1 and 2, allowed me to wake the device on button down, and use the debounce cap to see if the button was pressed recently (in the last second).

[image: Reset button circuit]